# How do you make an Arduino receive data through firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, arduino-uno, receiver

I've worked with firebase and arduino's before but never together. **I need to know how to make an arduino uno receive data through firebase**, however I do not need it to send data. **I have no idea how to do this, or if it is even possible.** I've looked at various articles of an arduino sending data to firebase, but never receiving data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you thinking to connect `Arduino` with `Firebase` you will need a backend. You can use `Firebase Admin SDK` to create a backend.

[This is a sample code for a backend](https://github.com/Sandun-Isuru-Niraj/webapi_for_arduino.git).

For more Information refer the [Documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup)

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your Arduino [saves data to the Firebase Database through the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/save-data). If that is the case, it can also [listen for data through the REST API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rest/retrieve-data).

There are several [libraries that wrap this REST API to make is easier to use with Arduino](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=firebase%20arduino). Instead of recommending one of those (which is off-topic on Stack Overflow), I recommend you try them and see what works best for you.

Comment: The question is about receiving data from firebase

Comment: The second and third link provide information on how to do that.